# Problem with adding items to a shopping cart again after one of them has been removed

Tags: php

I have four items in a shop. Adding them to the basket works without problems. If I remove the last added item from the basket, all works fine, I can add the same item again, but If I remove any other item from the basket which is not the last one then when I readd it, it overwrites the last one. 
Basically, readding an item works only when I remove the last item (readded item appears again at the bottom of the list).

My php code:
I have omitted session_start() and configuration from the top of the code. 
The products are all fetched from a mysql database.

```
// Adding products to the basket:

<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['shop'])) {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['shop'], 'product_id');
        if (!in_array($_POST['id'], $item_array_id)) {
            $count = count($_SESSION['shop']);
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id' => $_POST['id'],
                'item_photo' => $_POST['hidden_photo'],
                'item_photo_alt' => $_POST['hidden_photo_alt'],
                'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
                'product_price' => $_POST['hidden_price'],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
            );
            $_SESSION['shop'][$count] = $item_array;
        }
    } else {
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id' => $_POST['id'],
                'item_photo' => $_POST['hidden_photo'],
                'item_photo_alt' => $_POST['hidden_photo_alt'],
                'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
                'product_price' => $_POST['hidden_price'],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
            );
            $_SESSION['shop'][0] = $item_array;
    }
}


// Removing products from the basket:

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
    foreach ($_SESSION['shop'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['product_id'] == $_GET['id']) {
            unset($_SESSION['shop'][$key]);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Side note: **Never** store prices on the client side if you don't want to sell your items for free or less than the actual price

Comment: You overwrite your array by using count. You can better use your product id as index for your array. You can also get if the product id already exist and then increase the quantity. And I agree with B001, you can better store only the id and the quantity in your session and get the rest from the database when you wanna disply the cart

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. The price is taken from the database, can be changed in Devtools to 1 penny, but the PayPal button will still calculate the value using PHP code which fetches the price per unit from the database. This is from the product description: `<li>Price: £ <?php echo $row['price']; ?></li>` and this is from the PayPal Smart Button's JS code: `amount: {value: <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?>}` . I hope it makes sense, let me know if not. It works, anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, it uses the ID of the product as the key of the map. and replaces the item if it already exists, the delete function doesn't have to iterate over the items anymore:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['shop'])) {
    $_SESSION['shop'] = array();
}
// Adding products to the basket:
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['shop'][$_POST['id']] = array(
        'product_id' => $_POST['id'],
        'item_photo' => $_POST['hidden_photo'],
        'item_photo_alt' => $_POST['hidden_photo_alt'],
        'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
        'product_price' => $_POST['hidden_price'],
        'item_quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
    );
}

// Removing products from the basket:
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
    if(isset($_SESSION['shop'][$_GET['id']])) {
        unset($_SESSION['shop'][$_GET['id']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and is simpler than the code I had before.